# How to generate new random word element in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to generate a new random pick from the array elements. Currently, it randomly picks the first time it goes through array then the next pick is the same one, until 10 times.

```
colors = ["red", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "purple"]
comp_guess = colors.sample

correct_guesses = ["red","green","orange","yellow"]
total_guesses = 10
num_guess = 0

while num_guess < total_guesses do
  if(correct_guesses.include?(comp_guess))
    puts comp_guess
    puts "You got it right."
    num_guess = num_guess + 1
  else
    puts "You got it wrong. Guess again."
  end
  puts "The number of guess is " + num_guess.to_s
end
```

Output after this runs. I want new random numbers once it goes through the loop.

```
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 1
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 2
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 3
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 4
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 5
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 6
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 7
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 8
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 9
orange
You got it right.
The number of guess is 10
```

Comment: You mean a new random color? Just move the line that selects the random color inside the loop.

Comment: just sample every time inside the loop e.g. `correct_guesses.include?(colors.sample)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create an Outer Loop for Correct Answers

You can do what you want by iterating over your correct answers in an outer loop, and by using Array methods like [#shuffle!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-shuffle-21) and [#each_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-each_index) to handle your randomization. This is often preferable to #sample when you want to avoid making the same guess more than once. For example:

```
colors  = %w[Red Green Orange Yellow Blue Purple]
answers = colors.shuffle.take 4

answers.each do |answer|
  puts "Secret color is: #{answer}"
  colors.shuffle!
  colors.each_index do |i|
    guess = colors[i]
    print "Guess #{i.succ}: "
    if guess == answer
      puts "#{guess} is right. "
      break
    else
      puts "#{guess} is wrong."
    end
  end
  puts
end
```

Comment: Gnome, the player gets only a limited number of guesses. In the example it's 10, and as there are only six colors, that should be plenty, but you may want to treat that as a variable. Will delete this comment...

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nope. `colors.each_index` gives one guess per available color choice. By definition, you never need more than that if you can't duplicate guesses. If you want it *less* than that, then `(0...4)` or whatever is an option for the OP. You can drive yourself crazy trying to think of every edge case; canonical answers are great, but needlessly exhaustive answers just waste everyone's time. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

```
colors = ["red", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "purple"]   
correct_guesses = ["red","green","orange","yellow"]

total_guesses = 10
num_guess = 0

while num_guess < total_guesses do
  comp_guess = colors.sample
  puts comp_guess
  if(correct_guesses.include?(comp_guess))
    puts "You got it right."
    break
  else
    puts "You got it wrong. Guess again."
    num_guess = num_guess + 1
  end
  puts "The number of guess is " + num_guess.to_s
end
```

Comment: I know you were keeping to the OP's code as much as possible, but the OP should know that it would be more idomatic to delete the lines `num_guess = 0` and `num_guess = num_guess + 1` and replace the `while` line with `total_guesses.times do |num_guess|`. Possibly also change `else` to `end` and remove `end` before the closing `end`.